# AttributeError: 'QgsFieldComboBox' object has no attribute 'setPlaceholderText'

Tags: pyqgis, error, pyqt, actions, combo-box

I have a QGIS action to copy field name to clipboard and display a message to the user when copied. I manage to get the field name but when I try to use QComboBox function `setPlaceholderText()` to display the message in a `QgsFieldComboBox` like this :

```py
def copy_field(field, cb):
    pyperclip.copy(field)
    cb.setCurrentIndex(-1)
    cb.setPlaceholderText("Field copied to clipboard")

combobox = QgsFieldComboBox()
layer_id = '[%@layer_id%]'
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayer(layer_id)
combobox.setLayer(layer)
combobox.fieldChanged.connect(lambda x: copy_field(x, combobox))
combobox.show()
```

I get : `AttributeError: 'QgsFieldComboBox' object has no attribute 'setPlaceholderText'`

I don't see this function in c++ doc neither. I thought QGIS widget classes inherited from Qt classes with all properties.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The QGIS widget classes do inherit from the standard Qt classes most of the time. In this case `QgsFieldComboBox` inherits `QComboBox`, but the issue most likely is that the `setPlaceHolderText` method was only added with Qt 5.15.0, so chances are you are running a QGIS version that uses an older Qt build.

You could introduce a check such as

```
if QVersionNumber.fromString(qVersion()) > QVersionNumber.fromString('5.15.0'):
    cb.setPlaceholderText("Field copied to clipboard")
```

Also the introduction of `QComboBox::setPlaceholderText()` in 5.15 caused a bug in a related method, therefore the placeholder functionality was changed again in Qt 5.15.2 which caused the placeholder to not appear at all. According to the bug tracker this should be fixed with 5.12.9 [QTBUG-90595](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-90595).

So it appears you will need a QGIS with Qt build version 5.15.0/5.15.1 or >5.15.9 to use `setPlaceholderText`.